# Convert data type from bytea to polygon psql

Tags: postgis, geometry, geometry-data-type

I was trying to convert data type of my column from bytea to polygon,

```
ALTER TABLE polygon ALTER COLUMN geom type polygon using
geom::polygon;
```

But I got an error saying cannot cast type bytea to polygon. Is there a solution to change the data type of the entire column or I can only use casting from ST functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the PostgreSQL [`polygon` geometric type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html) with the PostGIS `geometry` type. They are are different approaches, and don't normally mix together.

Try converting the `bytea` to `geometry` instead:

```
ALTER TABLE polygon
  ALTER COLUMN geom
    TYPE geometry
    USING geom::geometry;
```

And if you want to restrict it to just Polygon geometry types with [EPSG:4326](http://epsg.io/4326), use typmods:

```
ALTER TABLE polygon
  ALTER COLUMN geom
    TYPE geometry(Polygon,4326)
    USING geom::geometry(Polygon,4326);
```